# Constraints causing textview to hide

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview

If I use a textfield the object will appear, but if I use a textview the object does not appear.  I believe the problem is in my constraints?

```
    commentTextView.text = "test text"
    commentTextView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    commentTextView.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
    commentTextView.font = UIFont.boldSystemFontOfSize(bodyFontSize)
    commentTextView.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

    containerView.addSubview(commentTextView)

    let views: [String : AnyObject] = [
        "containerView": containerView,
        "titleLabel": titleLabel,
        "commentTextView": commentTextView,
        "closeButton": closeButton]

    view.addConstraints(
        NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat(
            "H:|[containerView]|",
            options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(rawValue: 0),
            metrics: nil,
            views: views))

    view.addConstraints(
        NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat(
            "V:|[containerView]|",
            options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(rawValue: 0),
            metrics: nil,
            views: views))

    containerView.addConstraints(
        NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat(
            "H:|[titleLabel]|",
            options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(rawValue: 0),
            metrics: nil,
            views: views))

    containerView.addConstraints(
        NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat(
            "H:|[commentTextView]|",
            options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(rawValue: 0),
            metrics: nil,
            views: views))

    containerView.addConstraints(
        NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat(
            "H:|[closeButton]|",
            options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(rawValue: 0),
            metrics: nil,
            views: views))

    containerView.addConstraints(
        NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat(
            "V:|-(>=30)-[titleLabel]-" +
            "[commentTextView]-[closeButton]-(>=10)-|",
            options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(rawValue: 0),
            metrics: nil,
            views: views))
```

Any help on getting my textview to appear would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try and set a height constraint on your textview:

`commentTextView.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: commentTextView, attribute: .Height, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 50.0))`

a textfield knows its height without setting it explicitly (at least with the default border style). a textview does not.

Comment: Worked! not sure how I overlooked that.  Thank you so much.  I will mark this as the best answer in 10 min when stackoverflow allows me to